# include module routes in play framework

Tags: routes, playframework

I have created a module in my play application and the structure of the module is

myApp/app/builder/modules/design

In myApp dependencies.yml i have given

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - design -> design

repositories:
    - My modules:
        type:       local
        artifact:   /var/www/html/myApp/app/builder/modules/design
        contains:
            - design
```

In myApp routes

```
GET     /                                       Application.index
GET     /home                                   Application.index
GET     /design                                 module:design.index
```

The application runs successfully but when i access the design page in design module it throws error

```
10:13:58,247 ERROR ~ Cannot include routes for module design.index (not found)
```

What should i do to resolve this error.

When i add the module specification in application.conf

```
module.design=/var/www/html/myApp/app/builder/modules/design
```

Then it throws an error

```
The file {module:design}/app/controllers/Design.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The declared package "builder.modules.design.app.controllers" does not match the expected package "controllers"
```

Comment: if i add in application.conf it throws error but specified in dependicies.yml doesnot throws error but says cannot include routes

Comment: Seems that the package declaration is wrong builder.modules.design.app.controllers should be controllers.design

Answer (score 1):

@pere i have created the design page and modified the design controller package name to

```
app.builder.modules.design.controllers
```

and in application.conf i added

```
module.design:app/builder/modules/design
```

and in dependencies.yml as

```
require:
    - play
    - myApp -> design
```

While run the console showed deprecation in application.conf
and moudle design available in next line

But showed same error Then i 
I cut the builder folder and put into my myApp folder and changed the design controller package name to controllers and in 
application.conf

```
module.design:builder/modules/design
```

then everything is working

I found the error is in naming of the package
So i again cut into the app folder and changed the design controller package name to

```
builder.modules.design.app.controllers
```

when i run the application it shows

```
The file {module:design}/app/controllers/Design.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The declared package "builder.modules.design.app.controllers" does not match the expected package "controllers"
```

What could be the error

Answer (score 1):

we had the same problem with play 1.2.4

we import our modules over dependencies.yml and got the same error.
then, we deleted them from the deps.yml and just import over the application.conf.

works, although it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue has to do with the location of your controller. Controllers are expected to be under package "controllers". It can be "controllers.subpackage1.subpackage2..."

Your controllers doesn't seem to follow that pattern

Comment: i have created the design page and modified the design controller package name to

    app.builder.modules.design.controllers

and in dependencies.yml as 

    require:
        - play
        - myApp -> design

But still i am getting same error.

Comment: no, no, it can't be "app.builder.modules.design.controllers", it should be "controllers.builder.modules.design". Controllers first.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and figured that the problem happened because of a hyphen in my module name, I then changed it to underscores and it worked fine.

I can't test it right now but if I get some spare time I'll test whether it's because of the dot in the name of your project.